# bootstrap 3 popover on container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a popover that appears next to a certain `<div>` - not the `<div>` containing the popover trigger.

According to the bootsrap documentation, this can be achieved by setting the 'container' option.

Here is jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv6xd2py/4/)

Here's my html:

Click on button to see Popover

```
<a href="#" id="" class="btn btn-primary"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-container="#greendiv"
    data-original-title="Title"
    data-content="This is the body of Popover"
    data-placement="right"  >pop
</a>
<div id="reddiv" style='background:red;width:100px;height:100px;'>  
    red div 
</div>
<div id="greendiv" style='background:green;width:100px;height:100px;' >
    green div <br>
    I want popover to appear here to the right: 
</div>
```

and js:

```
$(function () { 
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();   
});
```

Popover appears, but alongside the trigger div not the div I want it to. Any ideas welcomed as to why this doesn't work for me ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sv6xd2py/4/

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I was trying to find a solution using data-* attributes as it is easier for my php logic. It would seem not  to be possible without additional javascript ? Also I clearly misunderstood the container option as pointed out by Krupesh,JesseEarley and timgvandijk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to add `data-*` attributes to the element you want `popover` append to. See working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iredjee/sv6xd2py/13/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="" data-toggle="popover" class="btn btn-primary">pop</a>

<div id="greendiv"
   data-original-title="Title"
   data-content="This is the body of Popover"
   data-placement="right"
     style='background:green;width:100px;height:100px;' >
    green div <br>
    I want popover to appear here to the right: 
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () { 
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").on('click', function(e) {
        $('#greendiv').popover('toggle');
    }); 
});
```

As alternative, you can use `options` for `popover()` plugin instead of `data-*` attributes. The official documentation will help you http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Answer (score 2):

As per i know meaning of `container` is to Appends the popover to a specific element container like body. so it affect when you scroll the page. that means `container` option is used to set static or dynamic possition of popover while scrolling.

for the functionality that you want please try the following code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('toggle');
  });
});
```

```css
#greendiv {
    background:green;width:100px;height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" id="test" class="btn btn-primary">pop
</a>
<div id="reddiv" style='background:red;width:100px;height:100px;'>
  red div
</div>
<div id="greendiv" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="Title" data-content="This is the body of Popover" data-placement="right">
  green div
  <br>I want popover to appear here to the right:
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Fiddle, the popover is functioning correctly, you're misinterpreting what "data-container" is doing. If you look at your Fiddle and view the source (I'm using Firebug), you will see that once you click "pop", that the popover does in fact attach itself to the #greendiv, it gets appended below the text you placed inside it.

Per the Bootstrap documentation:

> Appends the popover to a specific element. Example: container: 'body'.
>   This option is particularly useful in that it allows you to position
>   the popover in the flow of the document near the triggering element -
>   which will prevent the popover from floating away from the triggering
>   element during a window resize.

This doesn't say it changes the location of the popover.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the container attribute is for. To see the container attribute in action, you can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7KL4/) by [Rowan Freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944400/rowan-freeman). Switch out the two lines and scroll up and down to see the difference.

To achieve your desired behaviour, you have to put the popover-related data attributed on the `#greendiv` element and do something like

```
$(function () { 
    $('.popover-trigger').on('click', function() {
        $('#greendiv').popover('show');
    }); 
});
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv6xd2py/4/) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I bound click-'toggle' to the button and used popover-settings at the greendiv. Here is an example:
[DEMO-JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/51092wz4/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#popThis").on("click", function(){
        $('#greendiv').popover('toggle');
    });

    $('#greendiv').popover({
        title: "Title",
        content: "This is the body of Popover",
        placement:"right",
        trigger: 'manual'
    });
});
```